# Pod is in Pending state on single node Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, containers, kubernetes-ingress

I am using the `YAML` file to deploy the container on `Kubernetes` with some replication factor on a hosted machine.

## YAML File

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mojo-deployment
  labels:
    app: mojo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mojo
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mojo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mojo
          image: mojo:1.0.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000

---
#Services Info
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mojo-services
spec:
  selector:
    app: mojo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376

---

#Ingress Configuration
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mojo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: mojo
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: mojo-services
    servicePort: 80
```

Steps:

1. Build `Docker` image using `docker build -t mojo:1.0 .
2. `docker image ls` show me an image id.
3. Skipping `docker build` command to deploy image on container. Do I need to do it? or `kubectl` service will take care of it.
4. Run `kubectl apply -f Prod.yaml`. It shows

> deployment.apps/mojo-deployment created
>
> service/mojo-services created
>
> ingress.networking.k8s.io/mojo-ingress created

5. `kubectl get service` returns

   [image]
6. `kubectl get pod` returns
   [image]
7. `kubectl get deployment` returns
   [image]

Questions?

1. Do I need to build the container before deploying `YAML` file? I tried it but still `kubernetes` not running.
2. Why all pods are showing `Pending` status.
3. Deployment is also showing `pending` status.
4. Though I am trying to access the `Ingress` with :80 and cannot access it.

## Edit

pod description

```
Name:           mojo-deployment-6665bdc557-s57m7
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=mojo
            pod-template-hash=6665bdc557
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:            
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mojo-deployment-6665bdc557
Containers:
mojo:
 Image:        mojo:1.0
 Port:         9000/TCP
 Host Port:    0/TCP
 Environment:  <none>
 Mounts:
 /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-tjx6p 
(ro)
Conditions:
Type           Status
PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
default-token-tjx6p:
 Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
 SecretName:  default-token-tjx6p
 Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
            node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
 Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From
```

Message
    ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
    Warning  FailedScheduling  70s (x45 over 67m)  default-scheduler  0/1 
    nodes are available: 1 node(s) were unschedulable.

## Edit 2

After removing the taint from the master node. 
 1. `kubectl get node` returns

[image]

2. `kubectl get pod` returns

[image]

3. `kubectl describe node` : https://gist.github.com/amixpal/333bffd6ab91def749267f30d4ffb079

Comment: Can you please send the out put of the `kubectl describe pod <mojo-deployment-pod-name>`

Comment: Pending status indicates that the scheduler couldn't find a suitable node to run your Pod. As @MajidRajabi asked, we need the `describe` output to find the cause. Also, the container image you built will not be used according to your deployment YAML. The image will be downloaded from the docker hub. Make sure to tag the image during the build  (`docker build -t <username>/mojo:1.0 .`) and then log in (`docker login`)push it to the docker hub (`docker push <username>/mojo:1.0`). You can then use that image name in your deployment YAML `image: <username>/mojo:1.0.1`.

Comment: @Ansil I am not pushing to docker hub. Image is available on my machine.

Comment: @Majid Please checkout the Edit section

Comment: If you have only one node , then its fine to have it locally available as Default `imagePullPolicy` is `IfNotPresent` [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images). Seems like you have only one master and you have Taint on it.Please update `kubeclt get nodes` & `kubectl describe node <node>`.

Comment: @Ansil, For now, I have only one node. I have updated the edit section

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one node (master) , then usually a Taint will be added to it which will make master node unschedulable. Remove taint from the master (and all other nodes, if there is more than one) using below.

`kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`

Edit: Based on the node describe output, the CNI not ready.
Please make sure all CNI related Pods are running and healthy

Comment: Please checkout the `Edit 2` section

Comment: I can see `network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized`. Which network plugin you deployed? [CNI doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) and [CNI deployment for kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network). So you need to fix the CNI to get the node in schedulable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your container manifest should include downloadable docker image or k8s node should already contain docker image:

```
containers:
        - name: mojo
          image: mojo:1.0.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
```

Please answer: How your mojo:1.0.1 docker image appears on kubernetes nodes?

2. All pods wait to image be available.
3. Deployment wait for all pods will be in status `Running`.
4. K8s services make ingress be available after deployment be ready.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not pushing the docker image. can't `YAML` pickup from local machine?

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to worry about how to deploy a docker image to the machine. You can just save: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/ copy file and load: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/ archive on k8s nodes.